# Comma before and

Tags: american-english, writing

Is it wrong?

I 've read this at the Journal New York Times. We should be using a comma before and just when we have two independent clauses. That growth is connected to "expanded" of the first clause.

“It was a time when the airline expanded more than expected, and being part of that growth is a very good feeling.”

Answer (score 1):

The comma *is* joining two independent clauses in this case. The first independent clause:

> It was a time when the airline expanded more than expected.

The second independent clause:

> Being part of that growth is a very good feeling.

"Being part of that growth" is a [gerund phrase](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/gerundphrase.htm) that forms the subject of the linking verb "is," and "a very good feeling" is the [subject complement](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subjectcomplement.htm). Yes, the second independent clause does refer to content in the first independent clause, but that does not make it grammatically dependent.